# AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Installation fails on Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin, toolkit

I downloaded the latest Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers Luna 4.4 and tried to install the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse but got an error message:

```
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.driver
1.0.0.v201405191642.
```

I tried installing

1. using the [installation instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup_install.html)
2. installing from the Eclipse Marketplace
3. on OS X with JDK 1.8
4. on OS X with JDK 1.7
5. on OS X with JDK 1.6
6. on Windows using JDK 1.6

In the Eclipse log I get the following:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2014-06-28 14:14:23.076

!MESSAGE Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /Users/bernhard/Documents/EclipseDevelopment/eclipse/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.driver_1.0.0.v201405191642. !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2014-06-28 14:14:23.077

!MESSAGE The bundle manifest could not be read: /Users/bernhard/Documents/EclipseDevelopment/eclipse/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.driver_1.0.0.v201405191642

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2014-06-28 14:14:23.093

!MESSAGE An error occurred while installing the items !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2014-06-28 14:14:23.093

!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.driver
1.0.0.v201405191642, action=). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2014-06-28 14:14:23.093

!MESSAGE Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.driver
1.0.0.v201405191642.
```

So there are three error messages, all for com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.driver_1.0.0.v201405191642

1. **Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for**
2. **The bundle manifest could not be read**
3. **Failed to prepare partial IU**

I found the following Eclipse bugs that might be helpful for finding the right solution for the **Unable to acquire PluginConverter service** error:

1. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437466
2. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436372#c35

Comment: got the same issue - I assume they need to update aws plugin to work on luna

Answer (score 0):

Are you selecting the optional components for data tools?
[image]